# Arduino Nano RP2040 Connect does not work with Nano Ethernet ENC28J60 shield

Tags: arduino-nano-rp2040, enc28j60

I [modified](https://github.com/JAndrassy/EthernetENC/wiki/Nano-Ethernet-Shield) a Robotdyn ENC28J60 shield for a 3.3 V Nano by removing the logic level conversion IC and bridging its contacts (2-3 for INT and 5-6 for MISO).

But the Nano RP2040 doesn’t start the sketch with the shield on it.

Answer (score 1):

The Nano RP2040 Connect has the RP2040 BOOT pin instead of the classic's pinout RESET pin next to 5 V pin. The pin is labeled as REC.

The shield connects both RESET pins together so the RP2040 will always go into boot mode with the shield. You have to cut the pin or the PCB trace on the shield to disconnect the reset line from the BOOT pin.

pinout from [www.arduino.cc](http://www.arduino.cc)

[image]